# When using `pip download` how can I restrict the wheels to be only non-platform specific wheels

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, packaging

I am running the following on a different platform to which the package will be run on

```
pip download --dest wheels/ --no-cache-dir .
```

to download all the dependencies for my package. Not all dependencies have wheels and not all have wheels for the platform that this package needs to run on.

I want to prefer wheels over source if there is a `none-any` wheel distribution.

I have tried setting `--platform=none_any` but then it requires `--no-binary` to be set or `--only-binary` to be set. But I still want to allow mix of source and wheels.

Comment: Good question. I also have this problem when downloading package dependencies that mix platform-specific wheels (e.g. `--platform=win_amd64`) and source dists.

Comment: I think this issue speaks about the same thing https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5019